# How to set up radiobutton in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This program is to find how many voices are available in a PC, and I want to use `radiobutton` to chose a voice. Some PCs have one voice, others have many.

The programme works well, except the `radiobutton`. For now, to test my programme I use a function `sel` to see the selected voice. But later, it will be used in a another program to select the voice to use.

So, when the user presses the "Search" button, the PC's voices appear, with radio buttons besides them. For ezample, if they've got 2 voices installed, there will be 2 radio buttons, etc.

The radio buttons show up, but when I select one, all are selected, and I can't de-select.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCb4m.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3

def sel():
    selection = "Voice number #" + str(var.get())
    label.config(text=selection)

def voice():
    try:
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
    except ImportError:
        print("Requested driver is not found")
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Driver fails to initialize")

    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

    for voice in voices:
        r1 = Radiobutton(app, text=voice.id, variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
        r1.pack(anchor=W)


app = Tk()
var = IntVar()
app.title("Voices available.")
app.geometry("800x300+700+250")

label = Label(app, text="Voices on your pc." , font=("Helvetica", 20))
label.pack()
button = Button(app, text="Search", command=voice)
button.pack()

mainmenu = Menu(app)
files_menu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
files_menu.add_command(label="Quit", activebackground="red", command=app.quit)

mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Files", menu=files_menu)

app.config(menu=mainmenu)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should always post the code (that is specific to your problem) in text here, in a way that lets other users replicate the issue themselves. I can tell you that it looks like you name all of your radiobuttons `r1` which will not work. You could make an array of radio buttons and increment. `r[0]` and `r[1]`, etc.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma I remember the post waiting for edit approval from someone else. Did you perhaps "improve their edit", seems to me like they actually wrote the code from the image. They deserve the +2 for that.

Comment: @CoolCloud Improve edit gives them the +2. They had mistakes in it which meant it wouldn't compile, so I couldn't just approve, but had to improve. If you look at the edit history you'll see the approve and my edit happen at the same second :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give different value to each `Radiobutton` to distinguish between them all. So its like:

```
def sel():
    selection = f'Voice number #{var.get()}'
    label.config(text=selection)

def voice():
    ....    

    for idx,voice in enumerate(voices):
        r1 = Radiobutton(app,text=voice.id,variable=var,value=idx,command=sel)
        r1.pack(anchor=W)
```

This will return the index of the selected item from the list. But if you want the name of the voice, then:

```
for voice in voices:
    r1 = Radiobutton(app,text=voice.id,variable=var,value=voice,command=sel)
    r1.pack(anchor=W)
```

So as long as all the voices are unique, it will only select one option from all of them.

---

Make sure to never post pictures of your code again, relevant code have to be copy-pasted as text, else we cannot copy and work on it. It just makes our work and and your wait for answer longer.

Comment: @ Cool Cloud, Thank that work very well. Now i have to integrate this into my other programme to select the voice and use it.  So idx i assume is for index.

Comment: @MélissaCh. Yea that is short for index ;)

Comment: @ Cool Cloud, i have integrate this code (in a second window) to my other programme, but i can’t find how to make the radiobutton selection work. I think if because this print a index list. And like you say, it will select one option for all of them. It is possible to select a voice or another whit the radiobutton and add a command or a function to change it into my main programme. ( engine.setProperty(‘voice’, voices[2].id )  To be clear to change the voices[x].id in my fist window, went i chose one voice listed in my second window whit the radio button.

Comment: @MélissaCh. I have trouble following what you mean, could you ask a new question detailed? And link it here, ill take a look.

Comment: @ Cool Cloud, ok i will made a new question for that. Thank a lot.

Comment: @ Cool Cloud,  there the link to my other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67139453/how-to-bind-or-use-radiobutton-to-make-a-selection-use