# How to bind or use radiobutton to make a selection use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this programme who i use radiobutton to select voices from a pc.(some have only one voice other have more) so when a user choice a voices i want the programme use this voice to talk.

For now i can find the voices and click on radiobutton and i see the # of the voices in the pc. (this is in a second window, a Toplevel window) But after i can find a way to use it into my main programme(my root window) I have try different combinaisons in my root window, with var. Set, in my engine.setProperty("voice", voices[X].id) but nothing work. (X=voices number i wrote manually, 0 to 3 in my case. But i want this number to be set whit the radiobutton selection made by the user.)

Also i want to be able to set the speed rate of the voice in a other window, if the user want to slow down or make it faster. For that i presume it will be the same issu of the voice selection, because i will be in a other Toplevel window and this ajustement is in my root window.

I I'm stock here whit this. I have search on the web, and find nothing for now.
This is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3


def voice_info():
    voiceinfo = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    var = IntVar()
    voiceinfo.title("Voices available.")
    voiceinfo.geometry("800x300+700+250")
    label = tkinter.Label(voiceinfo, text="Voices on your pc.", font=("Helvetica", 20))
    label.pack(pady=10)

    def sel():
        selection = f"Voice number #{var.get()} selected"
        label.config(text=selection)

    def voice():
        try:
            engine = pyttsx3.init()
        except ImportError:
            print("Requested driver is not found")
        except RuntimeError:
            print("Driver fails to initialize")

        voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

        for idx, voice in enumerate(voices):
            r1 = Radiobutton(voiceinfo, text=voice.id, variable=var, value=idx, command=sel)
            r1.pack(anchor=W)
        label2 = Label(voiceinfo, text="Select a voice", font=("Helvetica", 20))
        label2.pack(pady=10)

    button = tkinter.Button(voiceinfo, text="Search", command=voice)
    button.pack(pady=10)

    second_menu = tkinter.Menu(voiceinfo)
    files_menu2 = tkinter.Menu(second_menu, tearoff=0)
    files_menu2.add_command(label="Quit", activebackground="red", command=voiceinfo.destroy)

    second_menu.add_cascade(label="Files", menu=files_menu2)

    voiceinfo.config(menu=second_menu)


root = Tk()
root.title("Voices test for A.I. - Other Files")
root.geometry("500x350")


def talk():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty("rate", 200)
    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
    engine.setProperty("voice", voices[2].id)
    engine.say(my_entry.get(1.0, END))
    engine.runAndWait()
    my_entry.delete(1.0, END)


label = Label(root, text="Enter your text here", font=("Helvetica", 18))
label.pack(pady=20)

my_entry = Text(root, height=8, width=40, font=("Helvetica", 15))
my_entry.pack(pady=5)

my_button = Button(root, text="Speak", command=talk)
my_button.pack(pady=20)

mainmenu = tkinter.Menu(root)

files_menu = tkinter.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
files_menu.add_command(label="Quit", activebackground="red", command=root.quit)

option_menu = tkinter.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
option_menu.add_command(label="Check voices", command=voice_info)

mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Files", menu=files_menu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Voices", menu=option_menu)


root.config(menu=mainmenu)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So if I am not wrong, after selecting voice(with radiobutton), you want to apply that voice too?

Comment: @Cool Cloud, yes exactly. Like this, user can chose the voice available they like on her pc.

Comment: I think if you put any code at the end of `sel()` itll get executed. So at the end, add `engine.setProperty("voice", var.get())` ?

Comment: @Cool Cloud, ok i try it but python yield me error.      command=sel(engine.setProperty("voice", var.get())))
TypeError: sel() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given       Also i have in the def talk() a code ligne for the voice property who set the voice, but there i have to do manually, and if i let the [ ] empty python yield a error too. I have try to put  between [ ] the sel() but this don't work too, it a string not a Interger and it say, unresolved reference "sel", i think it because the sel() function is in another window(topLevel).

Comment: That is not what I meant. Add that to the end of the entire function, but inside the function.

Comment: @Cool Cloud, sorry misunderstood. Ok i have put at the end of the function sel(). Just under label.config(text=selection).  A receive a error message. --Unresolved reference "engine"  --  I think it because in this function they have no engine defined

Comment: Hmm yes, for now, just say `engine = pyttsx3.init()` at the top, so it is defined.

Comment: @Cool Cloud, ok i do it. the error message it gone. but the voice don't change. It stay whit the selection in the talk() function, and when i clear the engine property in the talk() function the voice go whit the default voice, even if i chose one in the sel() function....

Comment: Can you update your code.

Comment: @Cool Cloud, ok i just update it.

Comment: Mmmm it must be the local `engine`. Okay, put `engine = pyttsx3.init()` outside all the code, below `root=Tk()` and remove all other `engine = pyttsx3.init()`.

Comment: @Cool Cloud, ok i have do this. but in the function voice() i have to let the engine in place, python yield error. so i put the engine right below the root=Tk() and remove all of the other. excep in the function voice(). nothing change it always the manual voices selection running.

Comment: Its just that when you use `engine` inside a function, it is different from other `engine` outside and insider other functions. So there is more than 1 `engine`, try to remove it all.

Comment: @Cool cloud, ok i have do that remove all the engine = pyttsx3.init() except the one right below the root=Tk. Always the same result, only the voice set manually in the talk() function.  I was thinking the radiobutton have no command to execute after the sel() function, it maybe the problem here. Maybe is in the sel() function that i have to place a command to change the voices in the talk() function? But this two function are not in the same place(window) so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution. First remove all the `engine` and place `engine = pyttsx3.init()` just below `root = Tk()`:

```
root = Tk()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```

Then notice in `talk()` you are always setting the property to the 3rd voice available with `engine.setProperty("voice", voices[2].id)`, so remove that and other non important stuff. Then it would be:

```
def talk():
    engine.setProperty("rate", 200)
    engine.say(my_entry.get(1.0, END))
    engine.runAndWait()
    my_entry.delete(1.0, END)
```

Now change your `sel()` function to get the voice list and then index the `id` out and then change the voice:

```
def sel():
    selection = f"Voice number #{var.get()} selected" # Consider #{int(var.get())+1}
    label.config(text=selection)
    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
    engine.setProperty("voice", voices[int(var.get())].id)
```

I also recommend you look into `threading`, and place your `talk` inside a separate thread, so it would not freeze the GUI while narration(`threading` might cause the GUI to crash too). Anyway, thanks for staying patient clearing all queries.

Comment: Thank a lot it work perfectly!  I very appreciate your help. Also i have learn a lot, thank. I will check "threading" this is a new term for me....